Identify Multiples Assembly Program (HLA)
Im really confused on how to swap I to J if I is less than J.
I need this to be outputted
Feed Me i: 10
Feed Me j: 20
EAX = 1
Feed Me i: 20
Feed Me j: 10
EAX = 1
Part of my code works but which is
Feed Me i: 20
Feed Me j: 10
EAX = 1
but I tried to fix the other part but I get
Feed Me i: 10
Feed Me j: 20
EAX = 0
program multiples;
#include("stdlib.hhf");

static
iDataValue1: int32 := 0;
iDataValue2: int32 := 0;

procedure multiplesOfAnother(i: int32; j: int32 ); @nodisplay; @noframe;
static
returnAddress : dword;
temp: int32;

begin multiplesOfAnother;
pop( returnAddress );
pop(j);
pop(i);
push( returnAddress );

// Initial check to handle the zero or negative values for j
cmp(j, 1);
jl NoMultiple; // If j is less than 1, it's not a valid multiplier

mov(j, EDX);

Adding:
add(j, EDX);     
cmp(i, EDX);      
jg NoMultiple;     // If EDX is greater than i, exit with no match
je YesMultiple;    // If EDX equals i, they are multiples
jmp Adding;        // Otherwise, keep adding

YesMultiple:
mov(1, EAX);
jmp EndProcedure;

NoMultiple:
mov(0, EAX);
jmp EndProcedure;

EndProcedure:
ret();

end multiplesOfAnother;

begin multiples;
stdout.put("Feed Me i: ");
stdin.get(iDataValue1);
stdout.put("Feed Me j: ");
stdin.get(iDataValue2);

push(iDataValue1);
push(iDataValue2);
call multiplesOfAnother;

// Check result
cmp(EAX, 1);
je Multiple;
jmp NotMultiple;

Multiple:
    stdout.put("EAX = 1", nl);
    jmp EndProgram;

NotMultiple:
    stdout.put("EAX = 0", nl);
    jmp EndProgram;

EndProgram:
stdout.newln();

end multiples;

